# Symbol change of line and polygon vector layer

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology, c++, vector-layer

I am trying to change the symbols of the polygon/ line vector layer using QGIS C++ APIs.
I am able to change the symbol of the point vector layer using below code. I am able to change the color for all types of vector files, but I don't know the names of symbols for using it in `QgsStringMap` as a value.

Code for changing the symbology of the vector layer.

```
layer->startEditing();
qDebug()<< "is editable " << layer->isEditable();
QgsFeatureRenderer * layerRenderer= layer->renderer();
QgsSingleSymbolRenderer *mSingleRenderer = QgsSingleSymbolRenderer::convertFromRenderer(layerRenderer);
QgsMarkerSymbol* symbol = new  QgsMarkerSymbol();
QgsStringMap mp;    // key - value relation  for symbol
mp[QString("name")]= QString("diamond");
mp[QString("color")]=QString("blue");
auto newsym=     symbol->createSimple(mp);
mSingleRenderer->setSymbol(newsym);
layer->setRenderer(mSingleRenderer);
layer->triggerRepaint();
layer->commitChanges();
```

in case of point vector layer

```
QgsStringMap mp;
mp[QString("name")]= QString("diamond");//put "circle/square/cross/reactangle etc" for different symbols
```

in case of line vector layer

```
QgsStringMap mp;
mp[QString("line_style")]= QString("dash") // or dot..but what  else can I put here in place of dash ?
```

in case of polygon vector player

```
QgsStringMap mp;
mp[QString("  ? ")]= QString("? ")   what should be places here in these question marks
```

I need to increase line symbols and polygon symbols.
but I don't know their names. I tried some but they don't work.
I am already using **QgsLineSymbol** for the line vector symbol and **QgsFillSymbol** for the polygon vector layer. Any lead will be beneficial.